# Envíar correo con password usando PHP Mailer

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmailer

Me gustaría enviarle un correo al usuario consultando su contraseña en dado caso que se le olvide únicamente ingresando su correo electrónico.

¿Cómo podría consultar el campo password correspondiente al correo ingresado???

PD: Aun no tengo el código de PHP, pero pienso mandar el dato de correo por post.

Registros mysql:

```
 |  id   |    usuario    |      correo      |   password   |

     1        lopez67       lopez@gmail.com     qwerty123
     2        xim477        xim@gmail.com         12348
```

Código HTML:

```
    <form>
    <div class="container">
        <h5 for="recuperar">Correo Electrónico:</h5>
        <input class="form-group col-md-6" type="email" name="recuperar" 
    class="form-control" id="emailRec" aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
    placeholder="Email">
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ingresa tu email 
    de registro al sistema y recibirás un correo electrónico con tu 
   contraseña nueva.</small>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Código PHPMAILER:

```
 <?php
 require_once("PHPMailer-5.2.11/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
 $mail->Port = 587;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

 $mail->Username = "my@mail.com";
 $mail->Password = "Mypsw";
 $mail->setFrom('my@mail.com', 'My Page');
 $mail->Body = 'Tu Contraseña es: '.$contraseña."\n\n"

 if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Error en Mensaje: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
echo "Mensaje Enviado";
 };
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema. Además, cuando un usuario olvida su contraseña no se le suele enviar por correo ni nada de eso, sino que se le genera una enlace para que éste cambie de contraseña o se le envía una contraseña o código temporal al correo electrónico con `X` horas de límite para que ingrese y cambie la contraseña.

Comment: Qué para finalidad de este Sistema, no se le tiene que generar una contraseña nueva más bien se le tiene que envíar de la Bdd la que ya tiene.

Comment: No entiendo bien. ¿Hay que enviarle la contraseña por email o hay que actualizar su contraseña en la base de datos? ¿?

Comment: Hay que enviarle por email la contraseña que ya esta almacenada.

Comment: Supongo que el usuario indica su nombre de usuario o su email. Recoges ese dato, lo mandas al servidor y lanzas una consulta a la BD donde busca la contraseña y se la mandas por email. ¿Dónde tienes ese código que recoge el POST del usuario y consulta a la base de datos?